# What is a good street photography lens for Nikon D750?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, street-photography

I've been using a 50mm ƒ/1.8 on my Nikon D750 for some months now, and I'm looking to upgrade the lens for a new experience. Which lens should I get next? I'm wanting to do street photography, just walk-and-shoot style of photography.

Comment: I dont think its a duplicate question. Its more specific for Nikon preference and which lens to get, focal length is different. The answer to the other question is not specific which lens to pick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using my kit lens AF-S NIKKOR 24-120mm f/4G ED VR with Nikon D750, and I'm very happy with it. This lens will give you both Wide as well as Telephoto experience. It produce very good and sharp images. You can try it.

Happy Photography!!!

Regards,
Vikas Aggarwal

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend the Nikkor 24-70mm f/2.8, it's a very good all-purpose lens for FF.

Any zoom will be a compromise compared to your prime 50mm f/1.8, but obviously you gain some flexibility.

Comment: I think that is what I need, an all purpose lens which I will on my body most of the time. thnks